# How does aufdrehen and aufmachen differ?

Tags: verb

If I want to speak about turning on something, how could I assess if aufdrehen or aufmachen is more suitable for describing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Aufmachen" means to open something in general. "Aufdrehen" means to open something with some kind of turning or twisting motion. Imagine, for example, turning the lid of a bottle to open the bottle. You might consider "aufdrehen" a special case of "aufmachen".

Both can be used literally or figuratively. You can say

> Sie macht den Kofferraum auf und holt die Taschen heraus.
> She opens the trunk and gets the bags out.

but also

> Er macht eine Buchhandlung auf.
> He opens a book store.

You can say

> Du musst nur die Flasche aufdrehen.
> You just have to open the bottle (by turning the lid).

but also

> Dreh bitte die Musik auf!
> Please turn up the music (the volume of the music)!

Comment: English uses "turn on" even if there is no actual turning; you can "turn on a light" by flipping a switch. This is an oddity of English and there's no reason to expect other languages to behave similarly.

Comment: I would like to add that neither "aufmachen" nor "aufdrehen" translate to "turn on" in any case I can think of. "To turn on" (in the meaning of "to switch on") translates to "anmachen" or "anschalten".

Answer (score 1):

*etwas aufmachen*: to open something (like a door, a glass of jam, a bottle of wine, ...)

*etwas anmachen*: to turn on something (like the light, the radio, a fire)

*etwas aufdrehen*: to open something by rotating its lid (like a glass of jam or an american beer bottle). Also used for a rotating water tap ("Das Wasser aufdrehen").

*die Musik aufdrehen*: to turn up (the volume of) the music. I imagine it could be used in the sense of "turning on the music" by people, but that's not its standard use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what it is. Examples: You say *ein Feuer anmachen*, but *Kannst Du die Lautstärke etwas aufdrehen?*.

Comment: Is there some general guideline for figuring out which verb it is